# Example step-by-step for simple JMS with Weblogic

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

Can any one please suggest me step-by-step example for creating JMS messaging , I am using Weblogic and eclipse. I am new to JMS. I am able to create weblogic Queue. But How we configure in eclipse and deploye application on weblogic. There are sender and reciver classes in eclipse.

But can someone explain me all seteps.

- What jars are required?
- How to deploye on weblogic?
- Application flow.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a good examples using EJB 3.0. See the following:

- [Getting Started with Message-Driven Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/ejb/messagedriven/conGettingStartedWithMDBs.html)
- [Processing JMS Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/ejb/messagedriven/conProcessingJMSMessages.html)
- [Basic JMS Demo using WebLogic Queue « Middleware Magic](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1987)

This is using [Oracle Workshop for WebLogic 10g R3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/workshop/overview/index.html).

Another example is in [Developing a Basic JMS Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jms/implement.html) for WebLogic 10g R3 and [Developing a Basic JMS Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24387/implement.htm#i1317694) for Oracle WebLogic Server
12c Release 1. In tha last case, may be you need [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html).